# python, using a twisted based proxy and keep trace of initial url

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

i have found on StackOverflow and manage to use a skeleton proxy based on twisted, but i wonder if it can help me to solve my problem :

i would like to be able to remember the dependencies bewteen the data that pass through this proxy, (i'am new to this network behaviour and not know how to do it) that is i would like to be able to determine that this particular ajax answer is following i call made by this javascript which was itself loaded from this url/html page and so on.

is it possible ?

(as another  example, i would like to be able to record/log in a similar way as the tree structure that is available when using Firebug, so that the proxy can log and say "i was first asked to go to this url", then, i see "this particular xyz.js file" and "this azerty.css" both where loaded as they depended on "this first url". Another example is for Ajax answer/response being able to tknow that it is linked to the initial page url page.à

(an so on, on a eventually recursive basis... asked in another I mean i need to determine which are the external files/data/ajax response loaded after by the initial html page passing through the proxy.)

can i do this kind of tracing from a proxy based on twisted ?

maybe i am wrong by thinking that a proxy can be able to do this without parsing/understanding the complete initial url. IF so my trouble wil lbe that i must handle Javascript and thus be able to parse and executing it :/

thanks

first edit : removing my attempts as asked. Sorry i have some difficulties in my question because i am not an expert in internet communication.

EDIT : Following Monoid comment, is it at least possible to be able to pair a particular Ajax answer with a javascript file or call from the proxy point of view ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question stating the problem separately from your attempts.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  Proxy cannot even distinguish two sets of files coming from two tabs opened in Firefox.

Comment: ok actually, you present another thing that i could have expressed... this is a part of my problem, can i be able to know from a proxy point of view which answers are part of the calls made from the first or the second tab. Are sure this is not possible for any ressources (js, css, ajax, etc.) ? maybe someone can think of a workaround ?